# Analytics Landing Page report: URL appended to "view" link

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

In our landing page reports our URLs are displaying properly - BUT - when we click the icon to view the page it tries to open a page with the main domain name appended at the beginning.

**This started after we:**

1. added a new subdomain/domain (cross-domain tracking is set up and
   working properly)
2. added a filter to display full url (to differentiate between multiple versions of our homepage)

**Domains:**

www.domain-A.com

www.domain-A.es

www.domain-A.co.uk

subdomain.domain-B.com

**Domain A appended to all landing page URL links:**

(displaying correctly but "view" links are 404's due to appended string)

www.domain-A.com/www.domain-A.com

www.domain-A.com/www.domain-A.es

www.domain-A.com/subdomain.domain-B.com

It always add the main domain at the begining and in Cross Domain it has no sense because I have diferent sites.

**The filter we added:**

1. In the Profile Settings page, click the Add Filter link.
2. Choose Add New Filter and provide the filter a name.
3. Choose Custom Filter and select Advanced on the Filter type settings.
4. Under Advanced settings:

   ```
    1. FieldA should be set to Hostname 

    2. FieldB should be set to Request URI
   ```
5. Set the values for both Field A and Field B to (.*), which is an expression that captures all characters.
6. Set the Output To --> Constructor option to Request URI and provide $A1$B1 as the value for that choice.

In Profile Settings, I have no Default Page (blank)

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

We have that filtered for some profiles too, and I seeing the same behavior i.e. Domain A appended to url links.

Being that the filter is adding the hostname to the URI, you're changing the way that the data is getting shown/reported. If you want to have the ability to click the icon to launch the actual page, you might want to create a new profile without that filter.